# Attribute is not added to xml document with lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, attr

This is my XML document, I am trying to add an attribute to item element, in the PyDev debugger in eclipse I see the attribute is added, but once I check the new tree the attribute is not added.

Here is the XML:

```
<root>
    <login branch="99">
        <command action="create">
            <goods_transfer type="9" book="true" nummer="692" branch_from="99" branch_to="90" CheckQty="0">
                <item article="100500213" main_price="49.950" EAN="5018746059881" amount="1.000" DateTime="20161202112913">
                    <size amount="1.000" index="59" EAN="5018746059881" Name="S 37/38" DateTime="20161202112913">
                    </size>
                </item>
                <item article="100500213" main_price="49.950" EAN="5018746059898" amount="2.000" DateTime="20161202112914">
                    <size amount="2.000" index="60" EAN="5018746059898" Name="M 39/40" DateTime="20161202112914">
                    </size>
                </item>
            </goods_transfer>
        </command>
    </login>
</root>
```

Here is my code using Python 3.4 from Anaconda:

```
with open(fileName, 'r+b') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    for _,element in etree.iterparse(f, tag='item'):
#After this line is executed I see the attribute is added
        element.attrib['DocumentCode'] = 'the value of the attr'
        element.clear()
#When I check the new file the attribute is not added
    tree.write(fileName)
```

What I aim for is this:

```
                <item article="100500213" main_price="49.950" EAN="5018746059881" amount="1.000" DateTime="20161202112913" DocumentCode='the value of the attr'>
                    <size amount="1.000" index="59" EAN="5018746059881" Name="S 37/38" DateTime="20161202112913">
                    </size>
                </item>
```

Comment: can you give an example of required output?

Comment: I edited the answer, added the example output I am looking for, please check the item element, the new attribute is the last one I am trying to add.

Comment: Remove the line :  `element.clear()`. *"Resets an element. This function removes all subelements, clears all attributes and sets the text and tail properties to None."* [[documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html)]

Answer (score 1):

This code should work as you want:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree


fileName = '...'
context = etree.iterparse(fileName, tag='item')

for _, element in context:
    element.attrib['DocumentCode'] = 'the value of the attr'

with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(context.root, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Little reminder: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if the answer is good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    tree = et.parse(f):
    [tr.attrib.update({"aaaa":"bbbb"}) for tr in tree.iter() if tr.tag== "item"]
    tr.write(output)
```

Here is possibility to do it with standart lib.